# How to resolve conda package install version conflicts

Tags: package, conda

What is the best practice for finding and resolving package version conflicts in a conda package install?

Sometimes when i try to install or update a package i get errors about conflicting package versions. One package wants version a, but another package won't work with version a, etc. Sometimes these conflicts are complex and even circular (unresolvable). Wondering if there is a package or application, etc that can make this easier to find the solution(s).